# XML Exception while parsing rest web service response JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jersey

i got this exception while i return this XML from rest webservice

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" +
    "<AccountID></AccountID>\n "
     + "<SR_ID></SR_ID><eCode>0</eCode><eDescription>Service Request created</eDescription>
```

and parsing response with response.getEntity.

```
    The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1397)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader.parse(XMLReader.java:222)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:477)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:682)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:650)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:299)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.readFrom(XMLRootElementProvider.java:117)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
```

Comment: Your XML is malformed: it does not have a root element.

Comment: Add a root element. Can be named anything, but there needs to be a top-level tag that wraps everything else.